# Quarkus 2.11.x no longer includes org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics:microprofile-metrics-api:3.0.1

Tags: quarkus, metrics, microprofile

I am currently migrating from 2.10.x (bom) and when I tried 2.11.3 (bom) I found that org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics.annotation.Gauge no longer exists. This comes from the following jar:-

org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics:microprofile-metrics-api:3.0.1

I feel like I must have missed something in the migration notes but I am unclear what to do about it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `2.11` is quite old, the most recent release is `2.16`, would upgrading be an option? --- Can you share your `pom.xml`? Are yo using smallrye-metrics or micrometer?

Comment: The [relevant part of the guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer#support-for-the-microprofile-metrics-api) might be of interest. Looks like mp-metrics must be included explicitly, and `micrometer` will add an adaptive layer to support it.

Comment: I will be migrating to 2.16 but wanted to migrate step by step and fix what breaks. We are using gradle. When I look at the dependency tree for io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:2.11.3.Final it does not include the above lib but 2.10.3 does.

Comment: Thanks @Turing85, I will try explicitly added the dependency. Strange that it was removed and not mentioned in the migration docs.

Comment: Let me know if it solves the problem. If it does, I'll post an answer.

Comment: It compiled but there was a runtime problem: Multiple producers of item class io.quarkus.deployment.metrics.MetricsCapabilityBuildItem. I think because we have both io.quarkus:quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus and io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-metrics. I will poke around some more.

Comment: [Smallrye-metrics is deprecated; micrometer is recommended](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-metrics). And yes: we cannot have both smallrye-metrics and micrometer on the classpath.

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer#support-for-the-microprofile-metrics-api (adding implementation("org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics:microprofile-metrics-api") seems to do the trick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the transitive dependency to `microprofile-metrics-api` was removed from quarkus version `2.11.x` onwards. Thus, if we want to use it, we have to add it.

For gradle, we add the following line to our `build.gradle`:

```
implementation("org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics:microprofile-metrics-api")
```

For maven, we add the following line to our `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>microprofile-metrics-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

(The snippets for the `build.gradle` and `pom.xml` were taken from [the official quarkus guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer#support-for-the-microprofile-metrics-api))